# Authenticate to an IP camera in an HTML and Javascript page

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, cgi

I am trying to capture and record the images from a Wisenet IP camera. 
I found the URL of the cgi for the Camera which provide the snapshots, with this:

```
http://192.168.1.100/stw-cgi/video.cgi?user=msubmenu=snapshot&action=view&Profile=1&Channel=0&SunapiSeqId=0).
```

Then I created a page in HTML and javascript which call the cgi recursively and show the images sequentially.

The problem is that I need to authenticate the session before starting my pages otherwise the cgi deny access.

I tried using authentication on the cgi url but this doesn't work:

```
http://admin:password@192.168.1.100/stw-cgi/video.cgi?msubmenu=snapshot&action=view&Profile=1&Channel=0&SunapiSeqId=3
```

Someone knows how to solve the authentication problem?